# Automatic keypress on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input area where a value has been preset. I would like to make it so that on page-load the "enter" button is pressed on the keyboard to submit the value.

Here is the code:

```js
$('#login-input').keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.which === 13 && $(this).val() != '') {
        player_name = $(this).val();
        logged = 1;
      }
```

```html
<div id="console_content">
  <label>Username:</label><input maxlength="10" class="textarea" id="login-input" autocomplete="off" value="Anonymous" type="text">
</div>
```

A solution where I would not need to press enter and the value is submitted is also welcome!

Comment: Just do `player_name = $('#login-input').val(); logged = 1;` when the page loads, after you've defined the vars.

Comment: Presumably the input is in a form, so just submit the form.

Comment: @RobG it is not a form, its just a simple input area

Comment: @StackSlave thank you so much! That was a far simpler solution, than I thought!

Comment: So you're not actually submitting the value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess code below would work.

```js
$('#login-input').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13 && $(this).val() != '') {
    console.log('triggered')
    player_name = $(this).val();
    logged = 1;
  }
})
const event = new Event('keypress')
event.which = 13
document.querySelector('#login-input').dispatchEvent(event)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="console_content">
  <label>Username:</label><input maxlength="10" class="textarea" id="login-input" autocomplete="off" value="Anonymous" type="text">
</div>
```

The [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event)

Comment: @Joe check the demo please

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to run after page loaded, use `onload` event. The solution may look like this:

```
 <script>
  function f() {
    // Test it:
    // alert("Hello, page loaded!"); 
    player_name = $('.some_place').val();
    logged = 1;
  }
 </script>
 <body onload="f()">
```

If you do want user to have a glimpse on your pre-filled login form and inform about what is happening, you may make a delay with `setTimeout` function, which will fire in 0.5 sec after `onload` event happened.

```
 <script>
  function f() {
    $('#some_element').text('Signing you in...');
    player_name = $('.some_place').val();
    logged = 1;
  }
 </script>
 <body onload="setTimeout(f, 500)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can call the event handler with a faked keypress like this:

```js
function kpress(e) {
 if (e.which === 13 && $(this).val() != '') {
  player_name = $(this).val();
  logged = 1;
  console.log(player_name,logged);
 }
}

kpress.call($('#login-input').keypress(kpress),{which:13});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="console_content">
  <label>Username:</label><input maxlength="10" class="textarea" id="login-input" autocomplete="off" value="Anonymous" type="text">
</div>
```

I use the output from the jQuery event binding as the object context for the `Function.prototype.call()` method and add a "simplified" event object as `{which:13}`.